# Changing colors of drawables in Android

Tags: java, android, user-interface, xml-drawable

I've made a function to change the colors of drawables in android. The problem is that it works only 60-70% of the times. I call it on the onCreate method of each activity of my app. (The color is saved in the shared preferences)
[As you can see in this image the color of the background drawable did not change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNhco.png)
It works mostly fine. But sometimes in one odd activity only the colors of some drawables change, and the others retain their default color.
This is the code of the function:

```
 public static void changeTheme(Context context) {
    int color = Color.parseColor(AppUtils.getColorSharedPreference(context, AppConstants.customCOLOR));
    if (color != -1) {
        Drawable unwrappedDrawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_untitled_4);
        Drawable wrappedDrawable = null;
        if (unwrappedDrawable != null) {
            wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(unwrappedDrawable);
        }
        Drawable unwrappedDrawableExit = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.logout_img);
        Drawable wrappedDrawableExit = null;
        if (unwrappedDrawableExit != null) {
            wrappedDrawableExit = DrawableCompat.wrap(unwrappedDrawableExit);
        }
        Drawable unwrappedDrawableFocus = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.focus_img);
        Drawable wrappedDrawableFocus = null;
        if (unwrappedDrawableFocus != null) {
            wrappedDrawableFocus = DrawableCompat.wrap(unwrappedDrawableFocus);
        }
        Drawable unwrappedDrawableSettings = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.settings_img);
        Drawable wrappedDrawableSettings = null;
        if (unwrappedDrawableSettings != null) {
            wrappedDrawableSettings = DrawableCompat.wrap(unwrappedDrawableSettings);
        }
        Drawable unwrappedDrawableHome = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.home_img);
        Drawable wrappedDrawableHome = null;
        if (unwrappedDrawableHome != null) {
            wrappedDrawableHome = DrawableCompat.wrap(unwrappedDrawableHome);
        }
        Drawable unwrappedDrawableBackArrow = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.arrow);
        Drawable wrappedDrawableBackArrow = null;
        if (unwrappedDrawableBackArrow != null) {
            wrappedDrawableBackArrow = DrawableCompat.wrap(unwrappedDrawableBackArrow);
        }
        Drawable unwrappedDrawableUnknownUser = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.unknown_user);
        Drawable wrappedDrawableUnknownUser = null;
        if (unwrappedDrawableUnknownUser != null) {
            wrappedDrawableUnknownUser = DrawableCompat.wrap(unwrappedDrawableUnknownUser);
        }
        Drawable unwrappedDrawableVerified = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.verified_user);
        Drawable wrappedDrawableVerified = null;
        if (unwrappedDrawableVerified != null) {
            wrappedDrawableVerified = DrawableCompat.wrap(unwrappedDrawableVerified);
        }
        Drawable unwrappedDrawableNoFace = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.no_face_detected);
        Drawable wrappedDrawableNoFace = null;
        if (unwrappedDrawableNoFace != null) {
            wrappedDrawableNoFace = DrawableCompat.wrap(unwrappedDrawableNoFace);
        }
        Drawable unwrappedDrawableWarning = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.warning);
        Drawable wrappedDrawableWarning = null;
        if (unwrappedDrawableWarning != null) {
            wrappedDrawableWarning = DrawableCompat.wrap(unwrappedDrawableWarning);
        }
        Drawable unwrappedDrawableMessage = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.message_new);
        Drawable wrappedDrawableMessage = null;
        if (unwrappedDrawableMessage != null) {
            wrappedDrawableMessage = DrawableCompat.wrap(unwrappedDrawableMessage);
        }
        DrawableCompat.setTintList(wrappedDrawable, ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
        DrawableCompat.setTintList(wrappedDrawableBackArrow, ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
        DrawableCompat.setTintList(wrappedDrawableExit, ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
        DrawableCompat.setTintList(wrappedDrawableHome, ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
        DrawableCompat.setTintList(wrappedDrawableSettings, ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
        DrawableCompat.setTintList(wrappedDrawableFocus, ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
        DrawableCompat.setTintList(wrappedDrawableUnknownUser, ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
        DrawableCompat.setTintList(wrappedDrawableVerified, ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
        DrawableCompat.setTintList(wrappedDrawableNoFace, ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
        if (wrappedDrawableWarning != null) {
            DrawableCompat.setTintList(wrappedDrawableWarning, ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
        }
        if (wrappedDrawableMessage != null) {
            DrawableCompat.setTintList(wrappedDrawableMessage, ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
        }

    }
}
```

And this is a sample call:

```
 if(Color.parseColor(AppUtils.getColorSharedPreference(LoginActivity.this,AppConstants.customCOLOR))!=-1)
    {
        AppUtils.changeTheme(LoginActivity.this);
    }
```

Comment: ***"As you can see in this image the color of the background drawable did not change"*** - I can't even differentiate which one is background and which one is foreground. What's exactly the color you want to change?

Comment: The curved triangle is a drawable ( part of the background having the default color), whereas the buttons and the edit texts are part of the foreground (their color has changed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found out the real problem.
this method needs to be called before super.onCreate();